# How can I TSLint on save in WebStorm?

Tags: typescript, webstorm, tslint

How can I **fix** my `.ts` files everytime I **save** a file in **WebStorm**?

I know that I can run **`tslint --fix`** after saving. I also know that I can <kbd>⌥⏎</kbd> + <kbd>⏎</kbd> on the current error in the file and that error will be resolved. But I am used to a different styleguide and it would save me a lot of time to have these style lint errors to be **auto fixed**:

[image: tslint error]

I cannot find the relevant settings in WebStorm:

[image: WebStorm settings]

I would also be completely willing to use a different **cli tool** to achieve **auto tslinting on save**.

Comment: File Watchers -- they run automatically on file save. 1) General info https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/File+Watchers+in+PhpStorm 2) Official Help page: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/file-watchers.html?search=file%20wa

Answer (score 19, accepted):

On-save actions are not currently supported by the platform, as files are auto-saved by the IDE - see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-6722.
If you need to run `tslint --fix` on `Save All`, set it up as a file watcher, and disable *immediate synchronization* for this watcher, so that it's triggered on explicit Save/changing focus.
See the simplest configuration below... You need changing the *Program* field according to your local settings

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Really nice solution:)